# Autocomplete ComboBox with typing user and get related data from database

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, autocomplete, dropdown

I have a `Combobox` and I want when user starts typing to get all data that contains the typed text from the database on time. I searched but more solution was working with catching all of data in load of form and binding to `ComboBox` and enable suggest append and etc. but I don't want to catch all data in first load of my program. I want when the user is typing to get related data and show `dropdown` below `ComboBox` and filter based on user typing.

Comment: So you want to pass a query to database whenever a user types a character in a combo box. That is the most absurd way of programming. That is the reason no one has written a blog on doing it.

Comment: I wouldn't use a combobox for this. Why not use a text input? (If you search for autocomplete WPF i'm sure you'll find some examples) Also you are right: you shouldn't fetch ALL the data from your database. Use a where and limit statement to limit the amount of results you get in your autocomplete.

Comment: Searching AJAX, Select2 and autocomplete would be the right starting points if you are so keen on searching :)